# Python/tkinter - Missing 1 positional arguement

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I'm trying to make a guess the number game where it picks a random number and then if you pick the right button it says you correct, and if you pick the wrong one it says incorrect.

```
print("~Guess the Number~")
print("Pick any number")

topFrame=Frame(root)
bottomFrame=Frame(root)

topFrame.pack(side=TOP)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#Random Number
import random
b=(random.randint(1,4))

#Functions
def number1(event,b):
if b==1:
    print("You guessed the correct number")
else:
    print("Not the correct number")

def number2(event,b):
if b==2:
    print("You guessed the correct number")
else:
    print("Not the correct number")

def number3(event,b):
if b==3:
    print("You guessed the correct number")
else:
    print("Not the correct number")

def number4(event,b):
if b==4:
    print("You guessed the correct number")
else:
    print("Not the correct number")

#Where the buttons are
button1=Button(topFrame,text="1")
button2=Button(topFrame,text="2")
button3=Button(topFrame,text="3")
button4=Button(topFrame,text="4")
button5=Button(bottomFrame,text="Quit")

#Binding the buttons
button1.bind("<Button-1>",number1)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)

button2.bind("<Button-2>",number2)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)

button3.bind("<Button-3>",number3)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)

button4.bind("<Button-4>",number4)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)

button5.pack()
```

It gives me:

```
__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: number1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

I don't know much about python yet :/

Comment: is this your full code ?

Comment: @Yousaf I have from tkinter import * at the top

Comment: the code indentation is incorrect. Indentation is critical with python code.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions expects two arguments

```
def number1(event, b):
```

but `bind()` sends always only one - `event`.

You can use `lambda` to send more arguments

```
 bind(`<Button-1>`, lambda event: number1(event, b))
```

---

BTW `<Button-1>`, `<Button-2>`, etc. means mouse buttons

`<Button-1>` is left mouse button.
`<Button-2>` is middle mouse button.
`<Button-3>` is right mouse button.

`BUtton()` has parameter `command=` to assign function, and it doesn't send `event`

```
 button1 = Button(topFrame, text="1", command=lambda:number1(b))

 def number1(b):
    # ...
```

But you could create one function for all buttons

```
def check_number(b, button_number):
    if b == button_number:
         print("You guessed the correct number")
    else:
        print("Not the correct number")

button1 = Button(topFrame, text="1", command=lambda:check_number(b, "1"))
button2 = Button(topFrame, text="2", command=lambda:check_number(b, "2"))
button3 = Button(topFrame, text="3", command=lambda:check_number(b, "3"))
button4 = Button(topFrame, text="4", command=lambda:check_number(b, "4"))
```